# return an array from function when dynamic argument is passed to the function in c

Tags: c

I am trying to return an array from the function, it is working fine as long as I am using hard coded value for size of an array. However, when I change it to dynamic (getting calculated from  `nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);`) then I am getting following error:

```
 -->gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘getRandom’:
test.c:14:16: error: storage size of ‘r’ isn’t constant
    static int  r[nproc];
                ^
test.c:18:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘time’; did you mean ‘nice’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
                     ^~~~
                     nice
```

when I change `static int  r[10];` to `static int  r[nproc];` its failing. I need to keep the size dynamic as the its going to be runtime calculated. Can someone please help me to get through this problem ?

Code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* function to generate and return random numbers */
int * getRandom(int nproc ) {

   printf("nproc is %d\n",nproc);
   //static int  r[10];
   static int  r[nproc];
   int i;

   /* set the seed */
   srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

   for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      r[i] = rand();
      printf( "r[%d] = %d\n", i, r[i]);
   }

   return r;
}

/* main function to call above defined function */
int main () {

   /* a pointer to an int */
   int *p;
   int i;
   int nproc;
   nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
   p = getRandom(nproc);

   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      printf( "*(p + %d) : %d\n", i, *(p + i));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Need to know how to achieve this in C PROGRAMMING

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning a variable length array from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823420/returning-a-variable-length-array-from-a-function)

Comment: The size of a static array must be known at compile time. You can only use a variable length array as an automatic variable. `static int  r[nproc];` is probably implemented before any value of `nproc` is known (before `main` is called). Suggest using `malloc`.

Comment: @WeatherVane is there any alternate way to keep it dynamic as per requirement, I cannot know the number of cpu  at compile time ?

Comment: I suggest using `malloc` and `free` after the caller has no more need for it.

Comment: `malloc` for `nproc` variable or for the returned array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

`int *r = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * nproc);// allocating for nproc integers`

Comment: Cast not need.  Consider `int *r = malloc(sizeof *r * nproc);`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define a `static array` with a non fixed size because it is like defining a global array with dynamic size. It is illegal in C because the global variable are part of the binary and must have a known size at the compilation.

If you really want to keep it `static`, you need to define the array of maximum possible size, and then pass the `nproc` value as the upper limit each time you call the `getRandom()` function.

Example:

```
/* function to generate and return random numbers */
int * getRandom(int nproc ) {

   printf("nproc is %d\n",nproc);
   static int  r[MAX_POSSIBLE_LENGTH];
   int i;

   /* set the seed */
   srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

   for ( i = 0; i < nproc; ++i) {
      r[i] = rand();
      printf( "r[%d] = %d\n", i, r[i]);
   }

   return r;
}
```

There is also a possibility to allocate/reallocate each time the required array size (by `malloc`/`realloc`) in the caller of `getRandom()` and the pass the pointer to it and the size to `getRandom()`:

```
void getRandom(int *pArr, unsigned int size);
```

In this case you won't need to hold any `static` arrays.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it with `malloc` ?

Comment: can you please check , I have tried implementing your suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658837/print-the-pointer-value-which-is-already-incremented

Comment: `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );` should be remove from `getRandom()`, else 2 quick calls to `getRandom()` return the same number.

Comment: @monk Sorry. I am having a very limited access to the internet right now. Will be able to take a look just in about two days... Sorry.